# svn status | sort - does not sort the output

Tags: linux, bash, svn, sorting

I would like to sort `svn status` output, but somehow this command

```
svn status | sort
```

does not sort the output.
Do you have any idea why?

for instance:

```
$ svn status 
?       idrd
?       core.7319
?       difftest
?       core.29328
A  +    rf_common/ext_api.sav
D       rf_common/ext_api/firewall_defs.h
D       rf_common/ext_api/rf_macro.h
?       firewall/src/hash2tuple.cpp.sav
!       firewall/src/hash2tuple.cpp
M       main.cpp
M       makefile

$ svn status | sort
A  +    rf_common/ext_api.sav
?       core.29328
?       core.7319
?       difftest
D       rf_common/ext_api
D       rf_common/ext_api/firewall_defs.h
D       rf_common/ext_api/rf_macro.h
!       firewall/src/hash2tuple.cpp
?       firewall/src/hash2tuple.cpp.sav
?       idrd
M       main.cpp
M       makefile
```

the question marks are not sorted, for instance.

Comment: What is the `svn status` output when you cannot `sort` it properly?

Comment: Tested on win7 and it sorts! What output do you get without sort and what output do you expect after sort?

Comment: It could be that some of the output is directed to stderr, so try `svn status | sort 2>&1` which redirects stderr to stdout

Comment: neither: svn status 2>&1 | sort nor svn status | sort 2>&1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you want `sort` to disable last-resort comparison.

Saying

```
sort -s -k1,1
```

for your input would yield:

```
!       firewall/src/hash2tuple.cpp
?       idrd
?       core.7319
?       difftest
?       core.29328
?       firewall/src/hash2tuple.cpp.sav
A  +    rf_common/ext_api.sav
D       rf_common/ext_api/firewall_defs.h
D       rf_common/ext_api/rf_macro.h
M       main.cpp
M       makefile
```

---

Quoting `man sort`:

```
   -s, --stable
          stabilize sort by disabling last-resort comparison
```

From [sort invocation](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sort-invocation.html):

> Finally, as a last resort when all keys compare equal, sort compares
>   entire lines as if no ordering options other than `--reverse (-r)`
>   were specified. The `--stable (-s)` option disables this last-resort
>   comparison so that lines in which all fields compare equal are left in
>   their original relative order.

Comment: Can you explain what is "last-resort comparison"?

Comment: I don't see how 'last-resort' conditions fits in the example I gave.

Comment: @devnull, thanks for the quote, but I can't seem to understand the relation either. Why does "last-resort", which kicks in when all keys compare equal, would prevent `A`, `M`, `D`, `!` and `?` to be sorted properly? Could it be that `!` and `?` have a special meaning to `sort`?

Comment: @Shahbaz If you _notice_ carefully, chances are that `-s` would affect the output (subject to the input, of course).

Comment: @RanRegev For your given example, though, telling `grep` by the starting and ending key might suffice.

Comment: I tried without -s, and it is fine. the -k 1,1 does the trick. Still I don't understand WHY do I need -k 1,1.

Comment: @RanRegev, that's a puzzle to me too. @devnull, you are right, `-s` would keep it stable. The output of `svn status` itself is quite chaotic though, (the `core.*` files divided by some other file for example), so in this particular case `-s` doesn't really help. Again, you are right though, generally it's good.